# splitting select query into two or more parts

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, plsql, query-optimization

I am using TOAD for Oracle. While i implement some sql queries i encountered these problem:

I am using a few tables that each of them has approx. 10M rows for a select query. 2 tables have over 70M rows data.

Let's say i have;

> a TRANSACTION table (prim. key: SQ_TRANSACTION_ID)
>
> a TRANSACTION_DETAIL table (foreign keys: RF_TRANSACTION_ID,
>   RF_PRODUCT_ID)
>
> a PRODUCT table (prim. key: SQ_PRODUCT_ID)

My select query is like;

```
SELECT TR.TRANSACTION_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PR.CD_PRODCUT_TYPE = 'A' 
                THEN TRD.CS_INVOICE_PRICE ELSE 0 END) A_PRODUCT_TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PR.CD_PRODCUT_TYPE <> 'A'
                THEN TRD.CS_INVOICE_PRICE ELSE 0 END) B_PRODUCT_TOTAL
  FROM TRANSACTION TR,
       TRANSACTION_DETAIL TRD,
       PRODUCT PR
 WHERE TR.SQ_TRANSACTION_ID = TRD.RF_TRANSACTION_ID
   AND TRD.RF_PRODUCT_ID = PR.SQ_PRODUCT_ID
 GROUP BY TR.TRANSACTION_ID,
       CASE WHEN PR.CD_PRODCUT_TYPE = 'A' THEN TRD.CS_INVOICE_PRICE ELSE 0 END,
       CASE WHEN PR.CD_PRODCUT_TYPE <> 'A' THEN TRD.CS_INVOICE_PRICE ELSE 0 END
```

Is there a way to split this query into two or more parts with referenced each other by using their foreign/primary keys? I mean like splitting into two parts that first part fetches A_PRODUCT_TOTAL and second part fetches B_PRODUCT_TOTAL. Each part's transaction id should match at the result data.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the results from each of the queries to look like?

Comment: I want the same result shown above query but i want it to be fethed from different select queries. For example; i split this query into two parts that first one: select transaction_id from transaction, transaction_detail where sq_transaction_id = rf_transaction_id; second one: select sum(...), sum(...) from transaction_detail, prodcut where rf_prodcut_id = sq_prodcut_id group by ... So.. At the and i should combine these select query results with referencing each other by transaction id.

Answer (score 0):

A direct translation of your query would be:

```
SELECT TR.TRANSACTION_ID, SUM(TRD.CS_INVOICE_PRICE) A_PRODUCT_TOTAL
  FROM TRANSACTION TR join
       TRANSACTION_DETAIL TRD
       on TR.SQ_TRANSACTION_ID = TRD.RF_TRANSACTION_ID join
       PRODUCT PR
       on TRD.RF_PRODUCT_ID = PR.SQ_PRODUCT_ID
 WHERE PR.CD_PRODCUT_TYPE = 'A' 
 GROUP BY TR.TRANSACTION_ID,
       CASE WHEN PR.CD_PRODCUT_TYPE = 'A' THEN TRD.CS_INVOICE_PRICE ELSE 0 END
```

However, I suspect that you don't want the second clause in the `group by`, because each transaction would be split into reows where the invoice price is the same:

```
SELECT TR.TRANSACTION_ID, SUM(TRD.CS_INVOICE_PRICE) A_PRODUCT_TOTAL
  FROM TRANSACTION TR join
       TRANSACTION_DETAIL TRD
       on TR.SQ_TRANSACTION_ID = TRD.RF_TRANSACTION_ID join
       PRODUCT PR
       on TRD.RF_PRODUCT_ID = PR.SQ_PRODUCT_ID
 WHERE PR.CD_PRODCUT_TYPE = 'A' 
 GROUP BY TR.TRANSACTION_ID;
```

The query for `'B'` would be similar.